# Countries End point is not returning anything although works in sandbox

Tags: reactjs, api

I am building a small Countries App in React.  The issue I have is that I have changed the endpoint and now it is not returning anything.  I checked this in Sandbox and it worked fine. Below is the code for the page that renders the details of the country.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { NavBarCard } from '../NavBar/NavBarCard';
import './DetailCountryCard.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function DetailCountryCard ({ match }) {
useEffect(() => {
    fetchItem();
    console.log(match);
    // eslint-disable-next-line 
  }, []);

  const [country, setCountry] = useState({});
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);




  const fetchItem = async () => {
    const fetchItem = await fetch(
      `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${match.params.alpha3Code}`
    );
    const country = await fetchItem.json();
    setCountry(country);
    console.log(country);
  };

  return (
    // <div>
    //   <h1>the country</h1>
    // </div>

    <div className={darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode" }>

        <NavBarCard handlechange={()=> setDarkMode(prevMode => !prevMode)} moonMode={darkMode ? "moon fas fa-moon" :
          "moon far fa-moon"}
          darkMode={darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}/>
        <div className="detailCard">
          <Link to="/">
        <button className="topButton myButton">Back</button>
        </Link>
          <div className="container">

            <img className="flag" alt="flag" src={country.flag} />

            <div className="countryName">

              <div className="NativeName">
                <h1 className="Country">{country.name}</h1>
                <h2>Native Name:</h2>
                <p> {country.nativeName}</p>
                <br />
                <h2>Population:</h2>
                <p> {country.population}</p>
                <br />
                <h2>Region:</h2>
                <p> {country.region}</p>
                <br />
                <h2>Sub Region:</h2>
                <p> {country.subregion}</p>
                <br />
                <h2>Capital:</h2>
                <p> {country.capital}</p>
                <br />
                <div>

                  <h2>Border Countries:</h2>{country.borders && country.borders.map(function(border){
                  return(
                  <Link to={`/DetailCard/${border}`}>
                  <button className="myButton"> {border} </button>
                  </Link>
                  )
                  })}
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="domain">
              <h2>Top Level Domain: </h2>
              <p>{country.topLevelDomain}</p>
              <br />
              <h2>Currencies: </h2>
              <p>{country.currencies && country.currencies.map(({ name }) => name).join(", ")}</p>
              <br />
              <h2>Languages: </h2>
              <p>{country.languages && country.languages.map(({ name }) => name).join(", ")}</p>
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  );
 }

export default DetailCountryCard;
```

All I get is blank page and in the console it saying that I am getting a status of 400.  Any help would be appreciated.  If I just put bra as the last three letters of the alpha code this is what I get.[image: Console of Api]

Comment: What endpoint did you change?

Comment: ````https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${match.params.alpha3Code}````

Comment: did you console log fetchItem and country... do they have values? or the api is not returning any data?

Comment: This is the api ```https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/BRA``` So I am looking to pass in the country alpha code.

Comment: Can you console log `match.params.alpha3Code` and check if the value is read correctly in your code? Also are you saying that when you directly call `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/BRA` in you code it works?

Comment: This is what I am getting from ```console.log(match.params.alpha3Code)``` ```DetailCountryCard.jsx:22 GET https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/undefined 400```

Comment: ok so the problem is that `match.params.alpha3Code` is undefined in your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212188/discussion-between-altbrian-and-jagrati).